# How to read the X in 5X4間?

Tags: readings, numbers, counters

A book about architecture I'm trying to read (it's a bit of a slog what with the technical jargon and such) contained this description of a temple building: 二重、初重５X4間、裳階　（もこし）　つき、上重４X3間. So it's two stories, the first being five rooms by four, with lean-to rooms attached, etc. I have a few questions about this. First, how is the "X" in 5X4 read? Additionally, I'm assuming that 初重 and 上重 are read しょじゅう　and じょうじゅう, respectively. Is this correct?

Comment: In fact that symbol is not X but × on computers.  It is the symbol for multiplication.

Comment: My computer is special.　(笑)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The English "by" is read 「かける multiply」 in Japanese. A 3x4 matrix, for example, is 「3かける4行列」 in Japanese. I assume your readings are right in the second part of your question, but can't seem to find them anywhere.

Comment: Occasionally you may see the contracted 「かけ」 also.

Answer (score 8):

I think you are making a big miskate. As for `５X4間`, you interpret it as 'five rooms by four', but it is not clear what that means, and probably that is wrong. `間` is a traditional unit for length. It is approx the long length of a tatami (about 1.8m). `５X4間` means a ５間 by 4間 rectangle.

Comment: Thank you, sawa. That makes a good deal more sense in the context of historical architecture. For anyone else who's interested,in this case, according to the Wikipedia entry (which I should have thought to look up beforehand), 間 is read as けん.