# How to say 24 divided by 8 equals 3

Tags: pronunciation, numbers

Pretty sure you have to use 割 but I don't know which pronunciation to use and how to say "equals" in this context.

Comment: Related: [How to read the X in 5X4間?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2914/542)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's read as 「24割る8は4」「にじゅうよんわるはちはよん」[nijuu yon waru hachi wa yon].
(I think we often say「24割る8イコール4」「にじゅうよんわるはちイコールよん」[nijuu yon waru hachi ikooru yon] after junior high school...)
Wait, 24÷8=...4? Isn't it 3?

Comment: Agh, the actual thing I needed translation for was different and equaled to 4. So I was trying hard not to make the mistake I ended up making.

Comment: Haha, math fail!  :D

Answer (score 4):

As Chocolate answered correctly, "equal" is usually omitted, but if you want to say it, it would be である, or なり (natural in this context but archaic). The one with イコール that Chocolate mentions is often heard, but I do not think it is a grammatical Japanese sentence. It is tracing the mathematical notation token by token.